Jito Bundles - in the same transaction?
I am exploring Jito bundles, and able to execute them in a test. But I am noticing that when my are executed they show as 2 transactions on explorer, instead of one.
Here is an example of my Jito bundles 2 txs:
https://solscan.io/tx/2JpTqsxv28cRB1KfnE2kPKuMjaSyPip5ZbunNnNpqXN1RQpoVU8QUzBZiEEinttvseYeNfZTd3YFRokP6GYosPCT
https://solscan.io/tx/51fk6k4YQSfKGVBZa3mZRTuVPBKXwaMJCQ7i8B2Y8qNFsKp31LCDD1d4Av7G6ufjhTkndp2D42EKQebKUNMgMpjK
Is this expected behavior?
I am seeing other Jito bundled transactions that look like this, executed in the same signature tx:
https://solscan.io/tx/5Vm9sYViF2VZV5dsD9tqYeYRbckhyn7ZyMNppWRtMto1PnyHvY5YN284mZy8xwPWpvsZMKpDjiZY6ToagVNEE3hu
Please let me know possible issues. Happy to supply coded if needed. Thanks!

hi can you share your script to send such bundle i'm having this issue "Detailed error response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Bundles must write lock at least one tip account to be eligible for the auction.","data":null},"id":1}
"

One of the most important features of Jito bundles is serial execution of multiple transactions, so this is completely expected behavior!
There's a nice writeup about them at https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/transactions/jito-bundles#what-are-jito-bundles
